# Como carregar plugins já configurados após página carregar por ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma página que tem um `form`

Nesse forme, contém alguns inputs, que possuem classes, por ex:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="marcara-cpf">
```

E a configuração desse de alguns plugins é feito em um arquivo js

```
$(".datepicker").config...
$(".mascara-cpf").mask("000.000.000-00")
```

Acontece que quando a página é carregada por ajax, ele não seta a configuração desses `plugins`, tendo que fazer novamente a chamada dessa configuração. O que torna repetitivo o código, todo lugar que tiver uma masraca de cpf, ter que fazer isso... aonde eu poderia só passar a `class` mascara-cpf para o input desejado.

Eu li em alguns lugares, que a implementação de `AMD` poderia resolver(usando require.js)

Mas não sei o quão trabalhoso será implementar esse require.js em todo app

Existe outra forma elegante de resolver esse problema com páginas carregando em ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como foi apontado pelo bfavaretto, os `Mutations Events`, tais como o `DOMNodeInserted` foram marcados como obsoletos, portanto os navegadores podem deixar de dá suporte aos mesmos.

Por um outro lado, poderiamos utilizar `Mutations Observers`, porém apenas o IE11 dá suporte ao mesmos, e sabemos o quão dificil é fazer o cliente entender que o IE é uma... (Salve Spartan!).

Então desta forma, o melhor a se fazer, é declarar uma função que realize o carregamento destes plugins, e para evitar que o mesmo plugin seja executado `n` vezes em um determinado elemento, é importante sempre delimitar um escopo para esta função.

Abaixo segue um exemplo:

```js
var content = $("#content");

var loadPlugins = function(escopo) {
  var maskCPF = $("[data-mask-cpf]", escopo);
  maskCPF.mask("999.999.999-99");
}

loadPlugins(document);
$(document).on("click", "#btAddMask", function () {
  $.post("Index/Home/0", {}, function(html) {
    var escopo = $(html);
    content.append(escopo);
      
    loadPlugins(escopo);
  }, "html");
});

//simular uma requisição AJAX via Post
$.post = function (url, data, sucess, dataType) {
  var row = $("<div>", { 
    "class": "row"
  });
  var maskCPF = $("<input>", { 
    "type": "text", 
    "data-mask-cpf": "" 
  });
  row.append(maskCPF);
  sucess(row[0].outerHTML);
}
```

```css
body {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<button id="btAddMask">Incluir Campo</button>

<div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <input data-mask-cpf="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O problema desse método é que os *mutation events* como `DOMNodeInserted` estão obsoletos, e podem não existir em futuros browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: Então neste caso ele vai precisar chamar o método 'loadContent' de forma manual, ou procurar outro evento que monitore quando um elemento DOM é adicionado.

Comment: Chamar manualmente parece uma boa no caso dele, já que ele sabe exatamente quando novos elementos são carregados.

Comment: Resumindo, criar funções para montar esses elementos e chama-los dentro da página que é carregada por ajax sempre, isso?

Comment: Sim, mas lembre-se de delimitar o escopo, por exemplo, se estiver adicionando apenas uma linha numa tabela, filtre apenas os elementos desta linha.

Comment: Para add uma linha na tabela dinamicamente, ai só para aquela linha que foi add né, pois o contrário ia setar o pluguin para todas, podendo perde valores, isso?

Comment: Normalmente eu crio funções loadmask e no window load eu chamo-as por ex, tem problema se eu passar $(.telefone).mask, mesmo não existindo nenhum elemento com a class telefone? Que ai no caso das mascaras eu uso uma funcao e chamo por tudo

Comment: @Rod, quando você faz $(".máscara").mask(), ele monta uma lista com todos os elementos com a classe máscara na página, então ele irá recorrer todos os elementos desta lista chamando o método mask para eles. Se a lista estiver vazia, então o método não será chamado.

Comment: Porém, para evitar que o método mask() seja chamado de forma repetitiva para o mesmo elemento, você deve delimitar um escopo para a sua seleção, digamos que você receba um html pelo AJAX, então pode fazer algo assim: var escopo = $(html); $(".mascara", escopo).mask(); desta forma apenas os elementos com a classe máscara que vieram através da requisição AJAX serão afetados.

Comment: @Rod, realizei umas alterações na resposta.